# How to set data source of sub-reports crystal report using vb.net?

Tags: sql, vb.net, crystal-reports

I am new in programming crystal Report, so please help me. i have main report with sub-report on it. i know already how to set data source of main report, the problem is in my sub-report. here's how i did for my main report:

```
Try
    open_con()
    Dim a As String
    a = "SELECT * FROM students where year_id=1"
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader
    cmd = New SqlCommand(a, dbcon)
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader

    'tblstud is a datagridview

    While reader.Read
        tblstud.Rows.Add(reader("name"), reader("address"),reader("grade_level"),reader("id_number"))
    End While
    reader.Close()
    cmd.Dispose()
    close_con()
 Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
 End Try

 Dim dtable As New DataTable
 With dtable
     .Columns.Add("name")
     .Columns.Add("address")
     .Columns.Add("g_lvl")
     .Columns.Add("id_num")
 End With
 For Each tblrow As DataGridViewRow In Me.tblstud.Rows
     dtable.Rows.Add(tblrow.Cells("names").Value, tblrow.Cells("addrs").Value, tblrow.Cells("lvl").Value, tblrow.Cells("ids").Value)
 Next

Try
    Dim rptDoc As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
    rptDoc = New stud_rep
    rptDoc.SetDataSource(dtable)
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

that's how i generated data and set it to the Crystal report, now the problem is in sub-report i don't know how to set data source, i tried to repeat that and set it to the next table (datagridview) and create another datatable but it shows empty.. i tried `rptDoc.OpenSubreport(0).SetDataSource(dtable2)`

hope anybody understand my problem.. thanks in advance

Comment: Do yourself a favor, and use a [SqlDataAdapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to load the datatable directly.  You can follow the example in that link, but substitute a DataTable for where it uses a DataSet.

Answer (score 0):

it might be little bit simple if you try like this

```
RptDocument.Subreports[0].SetDataSource(YourDataSource);
```

Comment: than you need check with crystal report, <br/> did you report and Sub report have proper link and also the same link available within your datasource you are passing ?  i.e. rptDoc.SetDataSource(dtable) and rptDoc.SubReports(0).SetDataSource(dtTable1)